# reading different data in same csv file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a csv file that looks somewhat like this:

```
#text
1  2  3
2  7  6
...
#text
3  5  8
...
```

So, basically, I have different data in the same file, separated by some text in between. I'm not sure how to sequentially read this data from the file without having to hardcode it in MATLAB using `csvread` or `xlsread`, followed by the range of cells i want read.

Comment: If you have a file that doesn't keep an specific format, like your example, I would suggest reading it line by line and processing each line. So you can apply different behaviors depending on the format and contents of the line.

Comment: There is a specific format... i have 7 lines of text followed by 50 lines of numbers. I was wondering if there is a way to use a for loop maybe.